# Is there a way to get the total number of video frames on Android?

Tags: android, media, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I am currently extracting, decoding, editing and re-encoding a video on Android using MediaCodec and MediaExtractor on Android. In the course of this process I would like to give users some information on the progress. I am already counting how many frames were extracted, decoded and encoded. In order to compute a percentage and to show users how far the process is, I would need the total number of frames in the original stream. However, I am unable to find a method in the MediaExtractor.

Does anybody know how I can get the total number of frames in a video before I start extracting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use total video duration and current frame timestamp to show the progress

no API for total frames is available in MediaExtractor

Comment: Mhm, you mean calling st.getTimestamp() when the frame is available? It seems to be something else because for the first frame I would get 74422225 instead of 0

Comment: It is in nanoseconds, divide it to 1 000 000 000 and you will get 0.74 sec

Comment: I know but this value is reported for the very first frame. However, I know the frame rate and I get notifications whenever a frame is available so I can calculate it. Nevertheless, your answer is the correct way to go.

Comment: well, not 0.74, but 0.074:) it seems to be ok. or audio in the stream started a bit earlier - this is a common case, or fps = 15 and timestamp is opengl case or in your pipeline shows frame end of life moment on a screen. something like that

Comment: also i recommend you to play with MediaComposer and effects from INDE Media Pack - it allows to make decoding\editing\encoding if a ten lines of code: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-running-samples

Comment: Down-vote for not explaining how OP can achieve this.