# How can I get video's frames per secon (fps) value programmatically in java Android

Tags: java, android, video, frame-rate

My question is rather simple but no luck finding answer: 
I have video file (mp4 container) and i want to know it's frame rate programmatically in android device.
How can I achieve this?

My first guess was [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) but there is no such constant to retrieve FPS or frame rate. I searched internet and stackoverflow too but no luck.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: never used it but what about android.media.MediaFormat?

Comment: @pskink MediaFormat's `public static final String KEY_FRAME_RATE` is used only for endoding videos and it's not possible to get videos fps of already encoded video using that. But thanks for answear.

As @weston pointed topic in which ther is no answer for my question in official api. I thought it's rather easy to get fps but it looks like it's not... Thank you weston for pointing this topic. +1 from me

Comment: There is no direct way to get the FPS, but you can use total video duration and current frame timestamp to show the progress no API for total frames is available in MediaExtractor. Pl. refer to the below url where they discussed bout the FPS calculation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750824/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-total-number-of-video-frames-on-android?rq=1

Comment: @shri Thanks for the link i will try to do some workaround with that. +1

Comment: @KarolŻygłowicz Did you come up with a nice way to calculate it? Please share it if you did.